# Adding values of variable form fields

Tags: javascript, html, input, sum

I have fields of `type='number'` in my form. These are dynamically generated by a database.

```
<input name="each[29]" id="form_29" placeholder="0.000" type="number" class="input" data-original-title="" title=""/>
<input name="each[30]" id="form_30" placeholder="0.000" type="number" class="input" data-original-title="" title=""/>
<input name="each[31]" id="form_31" placeholder="0.000" type="number" class="input" data-original-title="" title=""/>
```

The attribute `name="each[xx]"` is an ID of a category in the database. Here is the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" onClick="return calculAuto('form_29,form_30,form_31')">
```

### JavaScript

```
function calculAuto(v) {
    var mystr = v;
    var myarr = mystr.split(",");
    var cat = '';
    for (i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++) {
        if ($('#' + myarr[i]).val() !== '') {
            cat += $('#' + myarr[i]).val();
        }
    }
}
```

I want to calculate the sum of all the fields passed in the argument of the function.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing:

```
var cat = ''; //string
```

so with `cat += $('#' + myarr[i]).val();`
its appending the values, do:

```
function calculAuto(v) {
    var mystr = v;
    var myarr = mystr.split(",");
    var cat = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < myarr.length; i++) {
        if ($('#' + myarr[i]).val() !== '') {
            cat += $('#' + myarr[i]).val();
        }
    }
    console.log(cat);
    return false;
}
```